# ansible jinja2 - how to use "loop range" output in other "for statement"

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2

I want to use the n values in the next for statement and I expect output as router_0, router_1. But any optisons like router_[n], router_{{ n }}, router_(n) etc didnt work. How can we do this?

```
{% for n in range(0, 2) %}
 {% for rtr in web.router_[n] %}
  {% if rtr.interface.type == 'lacp' %}
  interface Port-Channel{{ rtr.interface.id }}
 .
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In vars.yaml, there are variables for paired routers, router_0 and router_1. I want to generate the config template for both routers at the same time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the name of the attribute

```yaml
{% for rtr in web['router_' ~ n] %}
```